# HowTo regex only domains from file

Tags: python, regex, awk

I have such complex file: http://regexr.com/3a8n4

I need to regex every domain out of it, meaning such a line:

`http://liqueur.werbeschalter.com/if/?http%3A%2F%2Fwww.vornamenkartei.de`

should yield me:

`liqueur.werbeschalter.com and www.vornamenkartei.de`

I could do this with python.

Any ideas?

Trying this:

`https?:\/\/(.+?)\/`

Should be ok, but I wanted to get also the other domains after the "http%3A..."

Comment: I am trying awk at the moment, no results so far.

Comment: Show what you have tried with `awk` and why it fails. Show what you have tried with Python.

Comment: @SirBenBenji try this grep command `grep -oP '(?<=http://)[^/]+|(?<=F)\w+(?:\.\w+)+' file`

Comment: I've recently written a mini article how to use Pyhtons `re`: http://martin-thoma.com/python-regex/ - does this help?

Comment: yes thanks. @Avinash Raj Quite the grep... not working here. though

Comment: I don't think negative lookbehind will work here due to the url encoded chars (it won't be fixed with). Plus the possibility of `https`

Comment: I would be interested in a grep only solution though

Comment: @David `grep -oP 'https?://\K[^/]+|(?<=F)\w+(?:\.\w+)+'  file`

Comment: David post as answer and recieve bonus. I needed time to check, because of this crippleware on MacOSX called Unix `grep -P` did not run, however enabling Linux on this machine like this, worked: http://www.heystephenwood.com/2013/09/install-gnu-grep-on-mac-osx.html

Answer (score 2):

```
(?:https?:\/\/|www\.)([^\/]+)\/.*$
```

Relatively simple, gets everything between the scheme and the start of the path, and captures it on group 1.

- `(?:)`: non-capturing group
- `https?|www.\`: matches `http` with a optional `s`, OR `www.`
- `:\/\/`: just the start of a URL, no special meaning. `\`s are for escaping
- `([^\/]+)`: creates a matching group (`()`) that matches any character except `\/` one or more times
- `\/`: matches a literal slash

See here: http://regexr.com/3a8n7

But ideally you wouldn't use regexes directly to parse the URL. Instead, use `urlparse`:

import re
import urlparse

```
with open("yourfile") as f:
    for line in f:
        referrer = re.match("Referrer: (.*)$")
        url = urlparse.urlparse(referrer)
        print(url.netloc)  # or whatever you want to do
```

Comment: I wanted the www. ones too.

Answer (score 1):

To get both the domain names and the URL-encoded domain names, you might want to try the following:

```
(?:https?(?::\/\/|%3A%2F%2F))([^\/%]*)
```

The reason for the `%` in the character class is in case there is a URL-encoded forward slash in the URL.

[Please see Regex Demo here.](https://regex101.com/r/lF0wS5/1)

Answer (score 0):

How about this ?

```
for url in urls:
    result = urlparse(url)
    print("{}://{}".format(result.scheme, result.netloc))
    unquoted = unquote(result.query)
    parsed_qs = parse_qs(unquoted, keep_blank_values=True)

    extracted_strings = list(parsed_qs.keys())
    for get_arg_values in parsed_qs.values():
        extracted_strings.extend(get_arg_values)

    for possible_url in extracted_strings:
        if possible_url.startswith('http'):
            parsed_url = urlparse(possible_url)
            print("{}://{}".format(parsed_url.scheme, parsed_url.netloc))
```

Python has means to parse urls and get params, we also need to process special case when get parameter doesn't have value and process keys as well.

**EDIT**: updated code